# how to use Mercurial's Buildbot hook with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, mercurial, buildbot, mercurial-hook

I am using this [buildbot hook](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot-contrib/blob/master/master/contrib/hgbuildbot.py) to send information about HG repository changesets to Buildmaster(build server) and the setup works fine with python2. Now I am upgrading Buildbot to 2.0.1 version, which supports only python3.5+ and the Buildbot version on HG(hook) should be same as that of Build server(master and worker); My issues are:

1. How to use `mercurial` python module in the hook with Buildbot 2.0.1(python 3.5+) - when mercurial`module is not supported by`python3`
2. is the setting `[hgbuildbot]
   venv = /home/buildbot/.virtualenvs/builtbot/lib/python3.5/sitepackages` enough to make sure the hook runs in virutalenv with python3

**update**:
Answer to my second issue is yes, tested with python2 virtual environment.